# ClassNotFoundException when i try to launch a BasicMapActivity within my App

Tags: android, here-api

Hey i try to include a HERE-Map within my App. I used the simple implementation example from the Developer's Guide (aka BasicMapActivity). But when i try click on a button to launch the BasicMapActivity.
I get this exception:

```
    JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.SQLiteDatabaseStatementResult" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/de.supermega.app-2/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.supermega.app-2/lib/arm, /data/app/de.supermega.app-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]"
```

followed by a StackTrace of over 9000 lines.

Does anyone know why this happens and got a solution ?

Comment: Include that class in `Manifest` file.

Comment: Something like this: `<activity android:name=".BaseMapActivity"`/>

Comment: it is already included

Comment: also the exception says it cant find the SQLiteDatabaseStatementResult class from the sdk.

Comment: Which version do you use for the gradle build tools? `com.android.tools.build:gradle:xxx`

Comment: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Comment: @elpatricko did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @AndrewJC no. I was sick i will look at it soon again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have minification (obfuscation) turned on for your build? If so, are you including the HERE SDK proguard rules as outlined here? : https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/obfuscation.html

Comment: I Think i made a mistake with the proguard file. i didnt included it for a specific build type. it works now. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the native library and java jar files come from matching releases? And also make sure the jar file is exported and actually in the final APK file? You can try to decompile the apk file to check if the HERE classes are in the APK.